# Webhooks in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, kubernetes-pvc

I have a requirement to watch for PVC creation events and handle it before forwarding to actual Kubernetes controller for processing the PVC creation. I went through many docs and feel webhooks can be used for achieving this. But would like to get expert opinion on the approach and best practices.

Comment: Could you please share docs that you referring to? Did you try to do already something with webhooks - if yes could you please share commands. Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: I tried https://docs.giantswarm.io/advanced/custom-admission-controller/



I see webhooks getting created but validation not happening as expected







Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:31:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.0+d5ed12c", GitCommit:"d5ed12c2580a64bf7125514c06435b4144a77e31", 
\